# $Z(G)[G,G]$ is of finite index in $GL_2(F)$ for a non-Archimedean local field?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, nonarchimedian-analysis

Let $G=GL_2(F)$, where $F$ is a non-Archimedean local field, for example, you can take the finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or $\mathbb{C}_p$.

We devote $Z(G)[G,G]$ is the subgroup generated by the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ and the derived subgroup $[G,G]$. So the question is why $Z(G)[G,G]$ is of finite index in $G$?

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb C_p$ is not a local field (although it can be seen from the answer that the assertion holds for it (or any algebraically closed field) as well).

Comment: The question boils down to understanding for which local fields (say, nondiscrete locally compact field) satisfy $K^*/{K^*}^2$ finite. This indeed holds iff the characteristic is $\neq 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's well known that in the situation at hand, the centre of $G:= GL_n(K)$ consists of the scalar matrices $\lbrace diag(a,...,a) = a \cdot I_n : a \in K^\times \rbrace$, and its derived subgroup is $SL_n(K)$ (the last assertion is true for any field except if $n=2$ and $K = \mathbb F_2$ or $\mathbb F_3$).

Now consider the group homomorphism $\det: G \twoheadrightarrow K^\times$ whose kernel is $[G,G] = SL_n(K)$ so that we have an isomorphism

$$G/[G,G] \simeq K^\times.$$

Note that an inverse of this map is given by $x \mapsto diag(x,1,...,1) \cdot [G,G]$, and since $diag(a,...,a) \cdot SL_n(K) = diag(a^n,1,...,1) \cdot SL_n(K)$, this isomorphism identifies $Z(G)$ with $(K^\times)^n$, so we get an induced isomorphism

$$G/(Z(G) \cdot [G,G]) \simeq K^\times/(K^\times)^n.$$

After thus translating to a question about the structure of the multiplicative group of $K$, can you finish this with specific knowledge about local fields? Note however (cf. YCor's comment) that the statement will not be true if the characteristic of $K$ divides $n$ (in your case $GL_2$, iff $K \simeq F_{2^r}((t))$).

Comment: Great but from $[G,G]=SL_n(K)$ you proved that $\det$ is an isomorphism

Comment: Showing a group has a finite quotient doesn't make it finite.

Comment: @SteveD: Very right you are, I was sloppy there. I think I was able to correct it now, using reuns' comment as well.